# Jquery get clicked element on delegated event

Tags: jquery

I've seen similar questions but they don't resolve this problem. I have an html that looks like this:

```
<div id="products" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="selected_product_div panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
              <a style="{cursor: pointer;}" class = "delete_product pull-right"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>                  
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, after the delegated event triggers, I'd like to get the `<a class="delete_product"></a>` element. But `$(this)` means the parent `<div id="products>` element.

```
$("#products").on("click",".delete_product", function(){            
        console.log($(this).hasClass(".delete_product"));
}
```

Of course, the console logs false. How can I get the clicked element?

`$(this).find(".delete_product")` is not an option since there are many elements with the `delete_product` class.

Comment: You could use var declaration for it. `var that = $(this).find('.delete_product');` inside the function, and you'll have that button in variable. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Mardzis Can't do that since there are many elements with the `.delete_product` class.

Comment: `$(this)` should be your link

Comment: So maybe `$('#products .delete_product')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#products").on("click",".delete_product", function(){  

        alert($(this).hasClass("delete_product"));

    })

})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
        <style>   
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
       <div id="products" class="container-fluid">
           
            <div class="selected_product_div panel panel-default">
                
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      <a  class = "delete_product pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-close">Click Me!</i></a>                  
                  </div>
                
           </div>
           
    </div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#products").on("click",".delete_product", function(){  

                alert($(this).hasClass("delete_product"));

            })

        })
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the target property of the event. here is the code wich will give you the exact .delete_product.

```
$("#products").on("click", ".delete_product", function (ev) {
    var $t = $(ev.target);
    $t = $t.is('.delete_product') ? $t : $t.parents('.delete_product');
    console.log($t.hasClass("delete_product"));
});
```

Comment: This fails when the `a` link has child elements, like `<a href="">Hello<b>there</b></a>`. When the click is on one of those child elements the target will not be the `a` element, while that is still the purpose of the delegated event handler.

Comment: yes that's why we are checking if it the target is .delete_product or not. if not then finding it's parent with that class. which makes it child proof assuming any child/parent does not have class delete_product. make sense? **$t = $t.is('.delete_product') ? $t : $t.parents('.delete_product');** this line makes it child proof. :)

Comment: You added that `if` and yes with that condition it works, but jQuery already does that task... it is better to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the dot in the `hasClass` argument. It is not a selector, but a name you pass:

```
$("#products").on("click",".delete_product", function(){
    console.log($(this).hasClass('delete_product'));
});
```

jQuery *does* provide the element matching the selector as `this`. As stated in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler):

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; [...] for delegated events this is an element matching `selector`.

For info only: there is of course another method, where you can (and should) use a selector (with the dot):

```
$("#products").on("click",".delete_product", function(){
    console.log($(this).is('.delete_product'));
});
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what the issue is?